# How to change font color in Notepad++ for highlighting (not as global change)?

Tags: fonts, notepad++, highlight

Just like the title says, does anyone know how to change font color in Notepad++ for highlighting, or boldface?

I'm asking about highlighting key words, not a global change.

I see this solution, but it's temporary. You lose the highlight changes if you close and open the file:

[Background color, notepad++ for highlighting purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176908/background-color-notepad-for-highlighting-purposes)

Thank you.

Comment: Is this what were you trying to change? (lets say blue to pink): 
|| https://www.computerhope.com/cdn/highlight.gif ||
Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To highlight a block of code in Notepad++, please do the following steps

1. Select the required text.
2. Right click to display the context menu
3. Choose `Style token` and select any of the five choices available ( styles from `Using 1st style`  to `using 5th style`). Each is of different colors.If you want yellow color choose `using 3rd style`.

If you want to create your own style you can use `Style Configurator` under `Settings` menu.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to choose a specific language to alter versus global settings.

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, though is seems like it, but: (note the 5 steps, with a 4.A)

[image]

You will need to check the various 'Style' options (step 3.) to see what is covered for the language that you choose.

Comment: this is not correct I think. The OP asks how to change the color in the following example (for example from blue to pink): https://www.computerhope.com/cdn/highlight.gif

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the Settings option in the main menu of the Notepad++ window. The Settings will be the 7th option from the left on the menu bar.
2. Under Settings, click the Style Configurator option which will be the second one. The Style Configurator window will open.
3. In the opened window, select the ‘Global Styles’ option in the Language section on the left. In the Style section adjacent to it, select the ‘Default Style’ option.
4. Now, in the Color Style section in the center, there are two options: Foreground color and Background color, with color boxes adjacent to them. To change the font color, click the color box next to Foreground color and select the color of your liking. There is also the option of more colors where you can add your own custom color or shade.
5. To change the background color, click the color box next to Background color and select the color of your liking.